# Mic to Speaker audio streaming in C#

Tags: c#, audio

I need to make a Windows applications which takes audio input (from microphone) and plays immediately to the speaker. If I explain in short, nI eed to make an application which can test my microphone.

I have been exploring Naudio and wmp libraries over the last 3 days but I couldn't get enough help to create it. But I know using these libraries there must be a way to create such an application.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two ways

1. [csaudio](http://aaronamberman.com/tutorials/csaudio.php) //hard way, but realy nice
2. [How-record-voice-from-microphone](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4967-How-record-voice-from-microphone.aspx) //easy way

**EDIT**

At list try this
[Voice Recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/) (here using [naudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) its opensource)

Comment: i have tried the " How-record-voice-from-microphone " this way but got an error at 

mciSendString("save recsound c:\\record.wav", "", 0, 0);
mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
Computer c = new Computer();   ///////////////// error here
c.Audio.Stop();


Error : does not recognize what Computer it. no reference of Computer class.

Note :  i have used all the classes mentioned in this article.

Comment: Add this Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to reference, and add this 
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;

Comment: VisualBasic.dll is present in .NET or in COM or i have to browse it?

Comment: @azeem in .net Sort item for easy find

Comment: :: got it... let me try it now. hope to get good results and accept it :-)

Comment: :: now i have to move forward to skip the recording the play it directly to the speakers. Have you any idea of this?

Comment: What do you mean under speakers?

Comment: I mean that what i speak in mic, i need to listen in speakers. simple i have to skip the recording step and need direct relation of mic and speakers.

Comment: Just do this *Process.Start("c:\\record.wav");* if you want playing sound in your program you need to do this 
    *SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\\record.wav");
    simpleSound.Play();*

Comment: :: I have done this and now my next goal is that i don't want to save the voice but just directly play it to speaker. i dont't need to save it on the hard and then play back as a Wav file reader.

Now the task is that as i speak in mic in the mean while it should be listen from the speakers.

Comment: It s hard with nadio so try this http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/help-please-streaming-microphone-18932.aspx

Comment: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/help-please-streaming-microphone-18932.aspx

this is using the directX library. i already have this link. and trying to do.

but is there not any solution with naudio... 
i am not getting any solution with naudio....

Comment: @azeem best way to know this asked about it in there forum http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/discussions good luck

Comment: @azeem all i know is you should to use *BufferedWaveProvider*

Comment: @azeem read this http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using.html